# get error jquery cookie not function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins

I have this function:

```
jQuery('#sort_order_by').change(function(){ 
        var productUrl = 'product.phtml';
        var value = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery.cookie('sortorderby', value);            
        var url= productUrl + '?sort_by='+ value;       
        window.location.href = url; 
        jQuery('#sort_order_by').val(jQuery.cookie('sortorderby') || 'helpful' );
    });
```

When executed, `jQuery.cookie('sortorderby')` has value `jQuery('#sort_order_by').val()` not set value of 
`jQuery.cookie('sortorderby')`.

I think that after the location load it does not re-run the code. So I tried create:

```
`jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#sort_order_by').val(jQuery.cookie('sortorderby') || 'helpful' );
 });`
```

This gives an error, *jQuery.cookie not function*.

Can anyone help?

Comment: In your file, did you import jquery.cookie lib ?? ex:` <script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>`

Comment: yes in file import jquery.cookie lib

Comment: Do you realize after you run the location line, the page will exit and not run the code after it?

Comment: I want after run the location line set jQuery('#sort_order_by').val(jQuery.cookie('sortorderby'). So you suggestion. @epascarello

Comment: If you want to run that on the new page, you need to run that on the new page.

Comment: it run in current page because i get var in url ex: localtion/?get=helpful.